# Aligning textbox and image in table cell

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to align textbox and image in same line so both of them occupy 100% of cell's width?  (without setting specific width to the textbox like width:95%)

```
   <table style="margin: 0px;float:left" border="1"  width="50%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
      <thead>
        <tr>
           <td class="title" colspan="2">
              Options
           </td>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td class="header" style="width: 110px;">
              Date                        
           </td>
           <td>           
             <input name="txtRelease" type="text" id="txtRelease" style="float:left;display: block;width: 100%;height: 100%;" /><input type="image" name="ImageButton1" id="ImageButton1" style="float:left;" src="http://www.classiclodges.co.uk/images/icon_date_picker.jpg" style="border-width:0px;float:right" />                       
          </td>                                            
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

http://www.webdevout.net/test?01O&raw

Answer (score 1):

You can have your image as background on the textbox instead. Try this on your textbox css.

```
background: url("http://www.classiclodges.co.uk/images/icon_date_picker.jpg") no-repeat scroll right center transparent;
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a wrapper element and absolute positioning.

***Live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/62sAU/6/

Alternative layout (added some padding): http://jsfiddle.net/62sAU/7/

Comment: it's not resizing when I set width to table

Comment: @urker In my demo, on the right there is the CSS panel. You have to put the `width` property inside the `table { ... }` list of properties. When I do it, it works fine.

Comment: @urker As @Shen pointed out, you could use a background-image for the calendar icon: http://jsfiddle.net/62sAU/5/ Then you would have to use JavaScript to detect if the user clicked on it. But that would not be an issue, since you need JavaScript to display the date-input control anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want like this ? http://www.jsfiddle.net/Tt5gu/

For this you have to expand width of  and set  width in pixel.

In summary, you couldn't set width values very well. You have to calculate widths :)

Comment: I hope for a solution without the need to enter values

Comment: i don't have to enter values, If you calculate percents correctly.

Comment: I mean also percents, the only width i want to set are: width of a table and with of a column